# Efficient cookbook recipe database with many independent ingredients and instructions per recipe

Tags: mysql

This might be a bit confusing, as I am a newbie to MySQL.

I have a cookbook with recipes, and I want to create an efficient database to manage these recipes so that later I can make an app.

Until now, I've been having trouble knowing if my tables are efficient enough, or if they are spending too many resources and if they could be improved.

```
CREATE TABLE recipesList (
    recipe_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    recipe_Name VARCHAR(100),
    recipe_Type VARCHAR(12)
);

CREATE TABLE ingredients(
    recipe_ID INT,
    ingredients_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, --This is just extra, to have a primary key
    ingredient_Name VARCHAR(120),
    FOREIGN KEY (recipe_ID) REFERENCES recipesList(recipe_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE instructions(
    recipe_ID INT,
    instructions_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, --This is just extra, to have a primary key
    instruction VARCHAR(1000),
    FOREIGN KEY (recipe_ID) REFERENCES recipesList(recipe_ID)
);
```

This is an image of an example of the table working.

Can you tell me if it is efficient, or is there any other way of making it? Also I don't know if this is the correct site to ask this, but if there's any other place, please feel free to tell me[image]

Comment: This is not the site to ask this kind of question, in spite of that you have shared your database code as a way to promote the discussion about the database model for your app. However, I think you need a link between the tables `recipesList` and `ingredients`. I can't figure out the table `instructions`. What's your point to declare that table?

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo Again, sorry, I'm pretty new. I didn't quite understand the part about promoting, but just so you know, the app is for me only. Also, the instructions table is for the directions to make each recipe. It will work in a similar way as the ingredients table. Another question, where can I actually ask this type of questions? Sorry again for the inconvenience

Comment: I used "promote" as a synonym of "encourage", "stimulate" others to discuss your solution. That's no relevant. I think you might share your question within other StackExchange communities focused on databases. It could be https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo okay, thanks for the help! Have a great day